# Minikube setup with Grafana and nginx ingress controller fails to honor root_url

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, minikube, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to setup a dev environment using minikube (On Mac, VirtualBox) with a custom webapp and grafana. I just can not seem to make the nginx ingress controller + grafana root_url option work together. 
Since Grafana, nginx and minikube are such popular tools, I must be overlooking something and I am completely out of ideas/luck. I would really really appreciate if someone can help me out here. I have spent quite a bit of time on this.

The host port 32080 is n/w mapped in Virtualbox to minikube port 32080
my-ingress-demo.com is added as 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts on my Mac. When I go to http://my-ingress-demo.com:32080/grafana/ I keep hitting the error (browser type: Chrome) that says

```
If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files 
1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath
3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn build
4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help`
```

First I installed nginx ingress controller using helm

`helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name r1 --set controller.service.nodePorts.http=32080 --set controller.service.type=NodePort --set controller.service.nodePort=8080 --namespace default`

---

My grafana deployment is

`apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: grafana-demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      podLabel: GrafanaDemoPod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        podLabel: GrafanaDemoPod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: grafana-demo
          image: "grafana/grafana:6.1.4"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL
              value: "%(protocol)s://%(domain)s:/grafana"
            - name: GF_SERVER_DOMAIN
              value: "my-ingress-demo.com"
          ports:
            - name: grafana-cntrprt
              containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 10
            httpGet:
              path: /api/health
              port: grafana-cntrprt
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/health
              port: grafana-cntrprt`

---

The corresponding service is defined as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grafana-demo-svc
  labels:
    svc_category: front-end
spec:
  selector:
    podLabel: GrafanaDemoPod
  ports:
    - name: grafana-svcport
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

---

My ingress is defined as follows

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  name: grafana-app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-ingress-demo.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/grafana/"
            backend:
              serviceName: grafana-demo-svc
              servicePort: grafana-svcport
```

---

I was expecting to see the login screen but I keep getting 404s. If I try to include the common rewrite rule in ingress config, i get too many redirects error

---

tried with even simpler setup of using docker-compose but still hitting the same issue. I must be doing something really stupid here

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  grafana:
    image: "grafana/grafana"
    container_name: 'grafanaxxx'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=%(protocol)s://%(domain)s/grafana/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this (see trailing slash)

```
GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=%(protocol)s://%(domain)s/grafana/
```

And this path in Nginx:

```
paths:
  - path: "/grafana"
```

Comment: That did not help. I still keep getting the same errors.
`t=2019-04-29T20:12:59+0000 lvl=info msg="Initializing Stream Manager"
t=2019-04-29T20:12:59+0000 lvl=info msg="HTTP Server Listen" logger=http.server address=0.0.0.0:3000 protocol=http subUrl=/grafana socket=
t=2019-04-29T20:13:04+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/grafana/login status=404 remote_addr=172.17.0.1 time_ms=2 size=22191 referer=
t=2019-04-29T20:13:04+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Complete`